# A battle between Maximo and Digenis in Greek Folklore

Tags: myth-identification, amazons

While working on an essay, I came across a book called the "The study of Russian folklore" which mentions encounters between an Amazon Maximo and Digenis Akritas and also between Siegfried and a warrior maiden in which the belligerents make love after the battle. Was it consensual sex or rape? Where can I find more information about these encounters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://hfc-worldwide.org/blog/2015/01/29/digenis-akrites/), it briefly mentions her, saying no one can match Digenes, not even Maximo with whom he committed the sin of adultery (non-forced sex with a married person). [This](http://www.ascsa.edu.gr/pdf/uploads/hesperia/147182.pdf) source describes them as lovers, but also mentions that it could have been against her will.

But, on literature stack exchange, an answer to [this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/5992/why-did-maximou-behave-in-this-way-towards-digenis-akrites?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) says there is nothing to imply sex was forced. It portrays her showing up with an army to win against a solitary man, Digenes. Finding this unethical, they have a one on one battle/duel. Maximo loses and Digenes spares her for her beauty. She convinces him to met the next day for another battle. Maximo is disarmed and defeated. Maximo then says, "I am a virgin still by none seduced. You alone have conquered, you shall win me all..." My interpretation of this is she is offering herself, rather then offering sex. But, that's what happened *willingly*.

Comment: You've named some useful sources but it would be great if you could somewhat expand your answer based on information drawn from these. Did Maximo lose twice?Did she offer sex or was it a classical example of rape in Greek folklore.

Comment: @Shatov   1a) Losing and being defeated can mean different things. So, while she was defeated, she did not necessarily lose. 1b) In the first battle, she showed up with an army against one man, Digenes. Maximo thinks this unethical and faces him on his own. Digenes wins and he spares he for he beauty. I would count this as a loss. 1c) In the second battle, Maximo is disarmed, counting as being defeated. 2) She did not offer sex, rather then offer herself. At least, that is my interpretation of the following quote, "You alone have conquered, you shall win me all."

Comment: That was quite convincing. I'll accept your answer as soon as you edit your answer to include your interpretation.

Comment: @Shatov , I edited my answer.